# Configure Linux kernel, modules, apps Makefiles to generate assembly files

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

Is there a way to configure the Makefiles compiling the linux kernel, modules and userspace applications leading to 
the generation of assembly files (.s - files)? I'm primarily interested in the assembly files for the ./lib and the userspace applications
(which I want to modify for some experiment and want to compile and integrate in a second run)? I'm aware of this requires finally to pass gcc the -S option, but I'm a liitle confused how to set this via         HOSTCFLAGS, 
CFLAGS_MODULE, CFLAGS_KERNEL, CFLAGS_GCOV, KBUILD_CFLAGS, KBUILD_CFLAGS_KERNEL, KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE, KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE variables etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use objdump -S to create an assembly file from a compiled .o file.  For example:

```
objdump -S amba-pl011.o > amba-pl011.S
```